# How can I use static polymorphism to convert between int and pointer types?

Tags: c++, c++14, static-polymorphism

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> void* ToPtr(T t) { return ToPtr((void*)t); }
void* ToPtr(void* i) { return i; }
void* ToPtr(int i) { return (void*)(long)(unsigned int)i; }

template<class T> int ToInt(T t) { return ToInt((void*)t); }
int ToInt(void* i) { return (int)(unsigned int)(long)i; }
int ToInt(int i) { return i; }

struct MyClass {
  template<class T>
  void* Find(T t) { return ToPtr(t); }

  template<class T>
  int FindInt(T t) { return ToInt(t); }
};

int main() {
  MyClass myClass;
  int myInt = 1;
  std::cout << &myClass << std::endl;
  std::cout << myInt << std::endl;
  std::cout << myClass.Find(&myClass) << std::endl;
  std::cout << myClass.Find(myInt) << std::endl;
  std::cout << myClass.FindInt(&myClass) << std::endl;
  std::cout << myClass.FindInt(myInt) << std::endl;
}
```

The program crashes in the first call to Find() but I'm not sure why. I'm using GCC 6.2.0, which is only C++14 compliant, otherwise I'd use constexpr. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should probably explain what you are trying to do here. Is the a reason to do 3 c-style casts in a row? Some kind of promotion trick?

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: What kind of "crash"? What actually happens?

Comment: Your template `ToPtr` will not be able to find the functions declared after it. You are calling the template version recursively to infinity.

Comment: My application has some legacy code that accepts both int and void* and stores them in void* data structures. Right now there's just a bunch of functions replicated for each version of the functions. I'm trying to reduce the list by using templates to generate the variants instead.

Comment: The crash? "Segmentation fault"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class T> void* ToPtr(T t) { return ToPtr((void*)t); }
```

This calls itself. Forever.

Since non-templates are preferred over templates, this is really easy to fix: you just have to put the non-templates *first* so that they're in scope within the overload above:

```
void* ToPtr(void* i) { return i; }
void* ToPtr(int i) { return (void*)(long)(unsigned int)i; }
template<class T> void* ToPtr(T t) { return ToPtr((void*)t); }

int ToInt(void* i) { return (int)(unsigned int)(long)i; }
int ToInt(int i) { return i; }
template<class T> int ToInt(T t) { return ToInt((void*)t); }
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0086dd0ab3b880e2))

When your program "crashes", you should be running it in a debugger. You'd have seen the stack overflow quite clearly, as hundreds of stack frames would all show the same recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

This function

```cpp
template<class T> void* ToPtr(T t) { return ToPtr((void*)t); }
```

calls itself indefinitely…

`ToPtr` is not a dependent name inside this function template (because a cast to `void*` is never a type-dependent expression [[temp.dep.expr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.expr#3)), thus, it is looked up at the point of definition of the function template, not at the point of instantiation. Since none of the other overloads of `ToPtr` are declared at the point of definition, the function template ends up calling itself. Make sure that all overloads of `ToPtr` are declared before the definition of your function template…

Apart from that, you should really never convert pointers to `unsigned int` or `int` as these types are not guaranteed to be large enough to actually represent a pointer value. Use [std::uintptr_t or std::intptr_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) for that if you really must do it…